# Could not cast value of type '()' (0x2c2fb50) to 'Swift.AnyObject

Tags: ios, swift, nsarray, swift2, nspredicate

Code:

```
let Predicate = NSPredicate(format: "self CONTAINS[cd] %@", searchText)
let result:NSArray  = arrCountryList?.filterUsingPredicate(Predicate) as! AnyObject! as! NSArray
arrCountryList = result.mutableCopy() as! NSMutableArray
```

I have a list of countries in an array.

I try to filter using NSPredicate, but it gives this error.

How to solve this?

Comment: What data type is `arrCountryList`? Why do you need to pass from `AnyObject!` before `NSArray`?

Comment: i got warning as Cast from 'Void?' to unrelated type 'NSArray' always fails that is why passed to nsobject

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let Predicate = NSPredicate(format: "self CONTAINS[cd] %@", searchText)

let result:NSArray  = arrCountryList.filteredArrayUsingPredicate(Predicate)

arrCountryList = result.mutableCopy() as! NSMutableArray
```